# Designing a MySQL database, should i rethink it entirely?

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

I have to design a system that focuses around information on businesses. For example some of the tables i would have would be "Owner", "Area", "Business Category", "Business Type", "Business", "Offers", "Events" etc.

I decided to group the information for each business under the "Business" table.

Example of "Business" table:

[Business]

- id
- Name
- Desc
- GPS_Coordinates
- AreaID
- OwnerID
- CategoryID
- BusinessTypeID

Now my concern is that despite most of my businesses have common fields some of them need extra fields (for example an accommodation might need price range or room types) and specific linking to other tables.

For example if i have a Business of type accommodation then we would need to link it to another table that would hold for example vacancies.

Example of "Vacancy" table:

[Vacancy]

- id
- BusinessID
- Title
- Desc
- Date

Should i create separate tables for each business type?

And if i do so then if i decide to link each separate business table with the "Offers" table (since every business could have an offer) i would need to have multiple foreign keys referencing to each separate table.

Example for "Offers" table:

[Offer]

- id
- Title
- Desc
- CreationDate
- ValidFromDate
- ValidToDate
- BusinessID

Which would be the most appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Better edit the question and You can provide some examples for each table and the common field you want to link between tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 "Owner", "Area", "Business Category", "Business Type", "Business(Name)", "Offers", "Events"
```

With the exception of "Events" and "Offers", they seem like they should be individual columns in a BusinessInfo Table. In the business info table, include a business ID, and include that business ID as a column in the other tables, so that you can join them when neccessary. My 2 cents

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9ea10/6

Comment: So for example i should link the "Vacancy" table with the "Business" table using the BusinessID as a foreign key, despite the fact that not every business from the "Business" table is going to be using the "Vacancy" table? (Since only accommodations will be using it).

Comment: Yeah, because that table wouldn't have to match up to every business ID. But you do need all businesses in the same table. then you could say in the vacancy table that has `business ID`, `vacancy amount` -- you just join it to the business info table on the business ID when you're selecting it, and you've got a hotel and its vacancy amount, and you don't have to set vacancy amounts for jewelery stores because maybe tables specific to jewelery stores are somewhere else. you can use foreign keys if you like

Comment: Do you reckon i should apply the same logic in order to have separate tables with extra fields that would link to each Businesse's type? For example when we have a restaurant business it would be good to know the menu or the dish of the day. Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you mess around with SQL Fiddle, I edited one into my answer, already started for you. I'm off to sleep

Answer (score 0):

Due to the vague nature of the question I would recommend reading what Dr Codd has to say about normalisation (Google it) - this should help steer your database in way that will be beneficial to you and your developers. HTHs Thanks //P

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating separate table for each business category, I would suggest you to create 2 table. One holds general fields and other holds specific fields for each business in json formate. so you need not to worry about how many specific fields any business have you just need to store them in json formate.
Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i thought about that at some point but i would prefer to see if there is a more db oriented way of doing it instead of having to work with that data programmatically afterwards

Comment: Another way to do this is using no-sql.